# Create CSV Issue

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a SQL script which runs. I then have another SQL script to create a .csv file. In the results file I just want to see the result rows. My file that is generated contains sql information before the results. I do not want this.

Code:

```
set echo off
set verify off
set termout on
set heading off
set pages 50000
set feedback off
set newpage none
set linesize 1000
set serveroutput off
set pagesize 0
set trimout on
set trimspool on


spool Weekly_Members_Vendors.txt

/*  SELECT   'Unique_ID, Name, Alt_Name, Entity_Type, Party_TypeReference_#, Addr1, Addr2, Addr3, Town, County, Postcode, */
/*                      Country,ALT_ADDRESS1,ALT_ADDRESS2,ALT_ADDRESS3,ALT_TOWN,ALT_COUNTY,ALT_POST_CODE,ALT_COUNTRY,NATIONALITY,  */
/*            DOB,INDIVIDUAL_ID,INDIVIDUAL_ID_TYPE,COUNTRY_OF_REGISTRATION,COMPANY_ID,COMPANY_ID_TYPE,SOURCE_COUNTRY,SOURCE_SYSTEM,TRANSACTION_TYPE'   */
/*  from     dual;  */


select   ''||Unique_ID||''||Name||''||Alt_Name||''|| Entity_Type||''||Party_Type||''||Reference_#||''||Addr1||''||Addr2||''||
     Addr3||''||Town||''||County||''||Postcode||''||Country||''||ALT_ADDRESS1||''||ALT_ADDRESS2||''||
     ALT_ADDRESS3||''||ALT_TOWN||''||ALT_COUNTY||''||ALT_POST_CODE||''||ALT_COUNTRY||''||NATIONALITY||''||
     DOB||''||INDIVIDUAL_ID||''||INDIVIDUAL_ID_TYPE||''||COUNTRY_OF_REGISTRATION||''||COMPANY_ID||''||COMPANY_ID_TYPE||''||
     SOURCE_COUNTRY||''||SOURCE_SYSTEM||''||TRANSACTION_TYPE
from     dbo.Temp_Weekly_Export_File;

spool off;



exit
```

The script is called by a .bat file.
Relevant Code:

```
sqlplus %CONNECT% @createTXT.sql   > File%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~6,4%.txt
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Seems to be a product specific issue.)

Comment: I am using an oracle database

Comment: How are you running the script? With those settings, running a script from SQL\*Plus with `@scriptname` (either interactively or from the command line, with or without the -s flag) won't include the SQL statements. SQL Developer before 4.2 (currently EA) will though, if you run what you showed as a script from a worksheet. Which client are you actually using? (I see you didn't add the sqlplus tag yourself...). Incidentally, why are you putting empty strings between each column, which does nothing; are they supposed to contain commas?

Comment: Thanks Alex, firstly I am need the empty strings (don't ask!). Secondly, I am actually calling this from a .bat file

Comment: I have added the relevant bat code

Comment: Are you talking about SQL statements in the file you are spooling to - Weekly_Members_Vendors.txt - or the SQL`*Plus banner (version etc.) in the file you're redirecting output to in the bat file?

Comment: It is the banner

Comment: Thanks Alex for your help